# Calling API from JQuery, override URL variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call an API which works like a charm, but when I try to add a new element in the database it gives an error because the url appends the id which is the phonenumber text field. But it's not yet in the database so it gives an 404 when it calls that url.

I'm trying to override the id variable in the save method (which will be called when a new element is created)

```
angular.module('movieApp.services',[]).factory('Movie',function($resource){
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/contacts/:id',{id:'@mobilePhone'},{
        update: {
            method: 'PUT',
        }, save: {
            method: 'POST',
            id:''
        }
    });
```

Somehow the id is still set, which result in a 404 call.

I tried it also the other way arround:

```
....
return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/contacts/:id',{},{
        update: {
            id:'@mobilePhone'
            method: 'PUT',
....
```

But it results in the same behaviour, it's now possible to save a new thing, but it's unable to edit an existing element.

I know I do something wrong but in my mind this makes sense.

Comment: _"because the url appends the id (which doesn't exist yet)"_ How can something that doesn't exist be appended? What is the actual URL of the request?

Comment: It takes the text field with the phonenumber (which is the id) and appends it, ill clarify it in the question.

Comment: _"the url appends the id which is the phonenumber text field"_ I don't see a problem. Either this **is** the id, then it should not matter whether there is already an entry in the db or not, or this is not the id, then `{id:'@mobilePhone'}` is not correct. If it's the former, then there is also no need for a `POST`.